# dht11 doesn't work on raspberry pi 3 stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch

## Situation

`DHT11` doesn't work on `raspberry pi 3 stretch`.

[image: DHT11]

This is my DHT11, and my connection is:

```
DHT11   <->   Rasp3  
VCC    <->   5V  
GND    <->   GND  
DOUT   <->   Pin#7 (GPIO 4)
```

and my code is on [here](https://pastebin.com/1UM8WXfG)

and the results from the code are always

> Data not good, skip

---

I confirmed **there's no error on `DHT11` module.**
I tested on `Arduino Uno`, it worked well.

How can I solve this?

ps.There's an ADC Converter `MCP3208` on my circuit, which I suspect to be the cause of error.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT** connect 5V to the Pi - you will blow it up.
The DHT11 will work from 3.3V.
You NEED a resistor ~4.7kΩ from 3.3V to DOUT - the device you pictured may have a resistor from VCC to DOUT.

You can use ANY pin.

> NOTE There is an Overlay for the DHT22 (I have not used this myself).

```
Name:   dht11
Info:   Overlay for the DHT11/DHT21/DHT22 humidity/temperature sensors
```

Comment: Yes, there's a register from VCC to DOUT. I charged 3.3V from Pi 3 to DHT11. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Without code it is not possible to say WHAT doesn't work.

Comment: There's on my code on my post. I solved this problem by activating 1-Wire. But it doesn't work completely. thx :D

Comment: @Hyuck-JunLee the DHT11 temperature sensor does not use the 1 Wire protocol. See my explorations https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dht11-sensor-1-wire-pi-arduino-mistakes-were-made-richard-chambers/

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to what I did with a DHT11 temperature sensor with first a Raspberry Pi 3 and then with an Arduino.

The Arduino code is at this URL: https://github.com/RichardChambers/anduino_uno/blob/master/project01/dht11_sensor.ino

One thing that I did was to write the DHT11 function, `onewireReadDHT11()` in my source code, so that I could collect statistics on how the read function was working. What I found was that the `counter` value check needed to be around 25 for a Raspberry Pi 3. However for an Arduino the comparison value was much less. You may need to increase that value to more than 30 for a Raspberry Pi.

So an edited version of your `read_dht11_dat()` function with the `if` statement modified follows. The `if` statement checks the value of the variable `counter` which is really the width of the pulse received.

One thing you can do is to print the actual data received out as hex values and check that if the `dht11_dat[]` data is all zeros or all ones.

```
void read_dht11_dat() {
    uint8_t laststate = HIGH;
    uint8_t counter = 0;
    uint8_t j = 0, i;
    float f;

    dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[1] = dht11_dat[2] = dht11_dat[3] = dht11_dat[4] = 0;

    pinMode(DHTPIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(DHTPIN, LOW);
    delay(18);
    digitalWrite(DHTPIN, HIGH);

    delayMicroseconds(40);

    pinMode(DHTPIN, INPUT);

    for (i = 0; i < MAXTIMINGS; i++) {
        counter = 0;
        while(digitalRead(DHTPIN) == laststate) {
            counter++;
            delayMicroseconds(1);
            if (counter ==255) break;
        }

        laststate = digitalRead(DHTPIN);

        if (counter == 255)
            break;

        if ((i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0)) {
            dht11_dat[j/8] <<= 1;
            if (counter > 25)       // this check is how long the pulse width is low.
                dht11_dat[j/8] |= 1;
            j++;
        }
    }

    if ((j >= 40) && (dht11_dat[4] == ( (dht11_dat[0] + dht11_dat[1] + dht11_dat[2] + dht11_dat[3]) & 0xFF ))) {
        f = dht11_dat[2] * 9. / 5. + 32;
        printf("Humidity = %d.%d %% Temperature = %d.%d C (%.1f F)\n",
               dht11_dat[0], dht11_dat[1], dht11_dat[2], dht11_dat[3], f);
    } else {
        printf("Data not good, skip \n");
    }
}
```